# How do I retry until a given date matches current date within For Loop Container?

Tags: ssis

#### Scenario:

I have a lookup table which has a date column, I need to look at this date column and check if its today's date, if not then wait for 5 mins and check the same thing again, and if the date is current send an email and exit the loop, and if after 6 retries if the date is not current execute a SQL task.

I have a ForLoop Container with the following settings:

```
InitExpression : @[User::Counter] = 0
EvalExpression : @[User::Counter] < 6
AssignExpression : @[User::Counter] = @[User::Counter] + 1
```

How / Where do I check the date :

```
SELECT ControlTimeStamp from LOOKUPTABLE
 WHERE ControlTimeStamp = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

#### Note:

I'm using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) 2008 for SSIS package development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want an approach like this. Execute your SQL Task to determine whether today is your date. From there you'll need to either sleep for N minutes or you'll want to send an email. The trick is to use an `Expression` on the `Precedence Constraint` between the Execute SQL Task the children.

My implementation differs slightly from what yours but the concept remains the same. I created two variables, @ActualDate and @ReferenceDate. @ActualDate is today and @ReferenceDate gets set from the Execute SQL Task. I then see whether they are equivalent. For what you have, if you get a result, then you know the send mail condition has been met so change your Expressions to meet that.

[image]

What isn't shown is how to terminate the loop early as I'm not quite certain how to do that.

Comment: In order to terminate the loop I just introduced a flag variable and inside the foreach loop I check if the flag is true exit the loop and I make the flag true whenever I want to in my SQL task.Thanks!